# Locked out of Ubuntu machine

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I recently made changes to my EC2/Ubuntu instances by installing OpenSSH, before I was able to SSH just fine, however now I'm getting this error:

```
ssh: connect to host shopious.com port 22: Connection refused
```

Any idea why? Here's what it says:

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to mysite.com [54.251.103.225] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 54.251.103.225 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host mysite.com port 22: Connection refused
```

Comment: Run SSH in verbose mode (`-vvv`) to generate some meaningful error messages...

Comment: @jasonwryan added more details

Comment: "Connection refused" most likely means there isn't anything listening on that port. The SSH server might not have been started, might be misconfigured, or might be listening on a different port.
I'm confused though; are you saying the issue occured when you installed OpenSSH?

Comment: @Ik yes that is correct, and now I can't get into my own machine

Answer (score 2):

"Connection refused" is a very clear message.
It means the server itself is running. But no service is bound to the given port.

In your case the machine is not running an ssh deamon or it is configured to listen on a different port.

Comment: so then how can I start ssh or the ssh deamon if I can't ssh to it?

Comment: You need physical access or some kind of external management interface. In case of EC2 there [seems](https://aws.amazon.com/instance-help/) to be a [management console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/) for that.

Comment: I am currently in my management console, but I don't see any option on starting ssh anywhere

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21461500/1870481

Answer (score 1):

If you can connect without SSH, log in and then activate SSH for this session using:

```
sudo service sshd start
```

and if you want this to be always done after reboot for example use

```
sudo update-rc.d sshd defaults
```

it will add sshd as a service.